# Sorting Multiple fields with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table that has a display (nvarchar) and sequence (int) field.

```
Select display,sequence from table 
order by sequence,display
```

What I would like to do is if sequence is 0 or null then sort by display else sort by sequence.

Comment: Have you looked at `CASE` expressions?

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample

Answer (score 0):

You need `case` expression :

```
order by (case when seq = 0 or seq is null then display else seq end)
```

Note : This assumes `seq & display` have same type.

Comment: This *assumes* `display` and `seq` have the same datatype, or that if they don't, the one with the lower precedence can be implicitly converted without error. That could well be an unsafe assumption.

Comment: sequence is a number and display is nvarchar

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian. . . What type of data available in display ? Can you edit the question with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This one works but not sure if there's a better way.

```
select
    display
    ,sequence
from

table 
order by 
    case when sequence > 0  then sequence
    else
        0
    end
    ,display
```